# Get number of rows from mysql where condition is met and the max value in 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table - order:

[image]

Currently using the following query:

```
select `id` 
from `order` 
where `userid_FK`=24242 and `productid_FK`=5
```

which returns - 32, 33, 34

How can I also select max(price) 197.0000 in one query is this possible (the max price for that user and productid)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using subquery in select list

```
select `id`, (select max(price) from `order` where `userid_FK`=24242 and `productid_FK`=5) as maxprice
from `order` 
where `userid_FK`=24242 and `productid_FK`=5
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `MAX` .

This will give you max price with one row.

```
select `id`,max(price) 
from `order` 
where `userid_FK`=24242 and `productid_FK`=5
```

If you want with all records:

```
select `id`,(select max(price) 
from `order` 
where `userid_FK`=24242 and `productid_FK`=5) ) as maxrate
from `order` 
where `userid_FK`=24242 and `productid_FK`=5
```